# SUBMIT後に画面上のエラーが発覚した場合、入力内容を維持したい（PHP）

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

http://www.phppro.jp/school/phpschool/vol6/1
こちらの記事にあるuranai_result.phpを作成して実行してみすると、submitボタン押下前に入力した内容は一体何だったのか、分からないはずです。
このサンプルでは入力項目が一つであり検知されるエラーも単一のため問題にならないと思うのですが、
複数入力項目があって、検知されるエラーがそれ以上に内部に用意されている場合、リクエスト時の入力内容が維持されていることがユーザにとって望ましい気がします。
エラー対象の入力項目だけを再入力すればよいわけで、その他入力項目まで再入力が強いられるのはユーザに易しくないと思いました。

## ====質問====

Webページの開発が乏しく、初歩的なことをお聞きしてしまいますが、標題の解決策を皆様はどういう方法で対処しているのでしょうか？ASP.NETで以前開発した際、この面ではViewStateという技術を利用していた記憶ですが、内部でhiddenの要素が生成されていたのですね、今回初めて知りました．．．。

尚、今取り組んでいるWebページですが、テーブルの中に複数行の入力項目がある感じなので、項目数が多いです。（テーブルの行をボタン押下で無限に増やせるようにしています=JQuery）

```
====PHP====
<?php session_start(); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>申請画面</title>
        <!-- Jquery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/entry.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1 id="logo"><img src="img/common_header_logo001.gif" width="254" heigth="25" alt=""></h1>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <div  class="ctrl">
                    <button type="button" class="iabtn">確認</button>
                    <input type="submit" value="更新" class="exbtn" name="exbtn"><br><br>

                    <?php include "php_classes/classes.php";
                        
                        if (isset($_POST["exbtn"])){
                            $sql1 = "ログインしている当事者の所属コードから、所属長をＤＢから取得するＳＱＬ文";
                            
                            try {
                                //DBへ接続 【php_classes/classes.phpに接続先は書いてあります】
                                $db = new ms0connect();
                                $conn = $db->dbconnect();
                                $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql1);
                                $stmt->bindValue(":branch", $_SESSION["所属コード"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                $stmt->execute();

                                /************************************************************************************************
                                * 所属長を導けた場合は、画面上の入力項目を業務テーブルに登録                 *
                                * 当画面の主目的を　つらつらとコーディングの予定。                      *
                                *                                               *
                                * 但し、所属長を導けなかった場合、入力内容を画面上に維持して登録できないことを画面に訴えたい！！*
                                *************************************************************************************************/


                                $conn = null;

                            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                                error_log("### SQL Serverデータ取得失敗 ⇒".$sql1."###".$e->getMessage(),0);
                                exit();
                            } 
                        }

                    ?>


                    <br><br>
                </div>
                <div class="appHeader">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>コード</td>
                            <td>品名</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="appLines">
                    <table>
                        <tr class="appLineDummy">
                            <td><input type="text" name="cd" style="width:45px; ime-mode: inactive;"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="amount" style="width:45px;"></td>
                            <td><button class="rowins" type="button">+</button></td>
                            <td><button class="rowdel" type="button">-</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="appBottom">
                    <table>
                        <tr class="appBottom">
                            <td>伝票備考</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="bottomtext" style="width:800px"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

====JS====
$(function() {
    //この画面ではエンターキーの操作を無効にしました
    $("*").keypress(function(e){
        if((e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode == 13)){ return false; }
    });

    //ブラウザの戻るボタン・ＢＳキーを操作しても遷移元ページへ移ることを防ぐ
    history.pushState(null, null, null);
    window.addEventListener("popstate", function() {
        history.pushState(null, null, null);
    });


    var $dummyRow = $("tr.appLineDummy");

    // テーブル行追加
    $(document).on("click", ".rowins", function(e) {
        var $row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
        addRowBelow($row);
    });
    // テーブル行削除
    $(document).on("click", ".rowdel", function(e) {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        $(row).remove();
        downtotalCalc();
    });

    //### 初回の画面呼び出し時 10行の明細を生成 ###//
    $(document).ready(function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            addRowBelow($dummyRow);
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: リクエスト先のPHPをフォームページ自身にして処理する（エラー時はリクエスト内容をフォームに再代入）か、送信時にCookieか、sessionStorageなどに保存するかですかね？どういったエラーを想定しているかによってかわるかと思います。

Comment: リンク先の次のページでリクエストの内容がデフォルトで表示されるようにプログラムされていると思いますが、これでは駄目ですか？http://www.phppro.jp/school/phpschool/vol6/2

Comment: 普通にphpに渡されたパラメータを元に入力フォームを表示し直すが、エラーを表示すると　ブラウザーの戻るボタンをクリックされてしまう事が有るので、エラー表示画面や確認画面では、ブラウザーの戻るボタンと同じ処理になる様に、onclickで,window.history.back(); を実行する事が多いです。

Comment: Myaku様・keitaro_so様・yyz様
皆様、お忙しいところ貴重なご見解を頂き誠にありがとうございます。
現在のところ、問合せに至ったWebページのFORM・アクションには何も記述していません。つまり自画面のPHPで画面上の内容を処理することを考えてきています。
本当に初めての開発で別のPHPにする必要性を感じたことがなかったので、そういう設計になってしまっています。

仮に、当該Webページうわっつら（入力内容）の牽制は間違いなくクリアできているとして、
ログイン時に控えられたセッション情報（ログインID）を元にDB検索を行ったら、ログイン時と状況が変わっていた。（そんな利用者は認められない、とか）
⇒入力内容を留めてSUBMITの処理を中断、そんなことを達成したいのですが．．．．

そもそも論として、別PHPにすることからでしょうか？
SUBMIT時の入力内容をどこかに蓄え、問題なければクリア、問題あればそこから復元、それはcookieかセッションで蓄えるべきであり、別PHPで対応するにしても
この方針が一般的な解決策になるのでしょうか？？
ご想像以上に初心者です、すみません．．．

Comment: @saya24 特にPHPファイルを分ける必要を感じません。……というのと、＞`自画面のPHPで画面上の内容を処理すること`：の意味が分かりません。何か勘違いがあるような気がします。
恐らく現在見ているフォームは`サーバでPHPが吐き出したHTML`を見ています。
一度吐き出した後のHTML(クライアント側)でPHP(サーバ側)の処理を行うことは出来ません。
ですのでサーバにデータを送る必要がありますが何処にsend(送信)していますか？
まずは、貴方が実装している現在のコードをお見せ願えますか？

Comment: Myaku様　お時間・ご見解を頂き誠にありがとうございます。
「現在見ているフォームはサーバでPHPが吐き出したHTMLを見ています 」
このご見解は、当方が参考にしたURLの記事についてのお話ですね？？
仰られるよう私は、入力の受付ページと返答ページ双方をuranai_result.php=同一という解釈をして参考にしていました。
「 一度吐き出した後のHTML(クライアント側)でPHP(サーバ側)の処理を行うことは出来ません。」
こちらのご見解、確かに理解しておりませんでした。これは非常にまずい？！
一先ずに抜粋ですが、当方のPHPを本文の末端に追加させて頂きました、ご確認頂けましたら幸いでございます。

Comment: input 以外の要素ってひょっとして、PHP側に渡ってこない？？Myaku様が仰られる「一度吐き出した後のHTML(クライアント側)でPHP(サーバ側)の処理を行うことは出来ません。 」は、このようなことを述べていた？？ただ今エラーがなかった場合の動作を、一先ず先行してコーディングし始めて気がつきはじめました。

Comment: でもこの記事を見ると捉えられるということ？？https://teratail.com/questions/4328

Comment: @saya24 恐らく疑問だらけで収拾がつかない状態なのだと思いますが、疑問乱立の状態だと何処に回答するか分からず回答が付けられません。(…内容を見ている私でも何処から回答するべきか迷います)、とりあえずコードを記載頂いているので一度確認しますね。(あと`@user`で特定の人にコメントの通知を飛ばすことができます。これがないと通知が飛んできません…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

結構ザックリ書きました。
行き成り全部作って完成を目指すより、
最小の機能で作って、機能を追加していく方が学びやすく実装しやすいのではないでしょうか？
("フォームからPHPにリクエストする"→"PHPでリクエストデータからフォームを作成する"
→"リクエストデータを処理しエラー判定する"のように段階を踏んでは？)

1. PHPが処理されるタイミング
   PHPはサーバ側のスクリプト言語なのでJavaScriptのようにクライアント側では動作できません。
   PHPページのソースをブラウザで見ると分かるかと思いますが、その中にPHPの記述は一切ないかと思います。
   それはサーバ側で既にPHPを処理し終わっていて、クライアント(ブラウザ)に来るときにはHTMLで作られたWebページになっているからです。
2. 同じnameをForm内で複数使う
   同じnameを複数使用するとリクエストを受け取った際に最初の1つ目の値しか取れません。
   もし、同じnameを使用するのであれば`name="label[]"`のように`[]`を使用し配列で渡しましょう。
3. リクエストに不備があった場合にHTMLに再展開する
   もし、エラーが発生した場合に再度展開するのであれば、テーブルはPHPで出力しておきましょう。
4. (蛇足)デザイン次第ですがtableにラベル(タイトル)を付けるのであれば`<thead>`内で`<th>`を使用するのが良いかもしれません。

※ミニマムで自己POST

```
<?php 
//初期化(エラーがなかったり、初回の場合に空の入力フォーム出力用)
$datas = array(
    'cd'=>array(""),
    'amount'=>array("")
);
//cd及びamountがリクエストに存在し、値を持っている場合
if(!empty($_POST['cd']) && !empty($_POST['amount'])){
    //色々処理
    if(true){//もしエラーだったら(サンプル用にとりあえずtrueで処理)
        //エラーデータが存在するなら展開用配列に代入
        $datas['cd'] = $_POST['cd'];
        $datas['amount'] = $_POST['amount'];
    }
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- 省略 -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <!-- 省略 -->
            <form method="post" action="./index.php"><!-- actionに、このphpファイル自身を指定する -->
                <div  class="ctrl">
                    <input type="submit" value="更新" class="exbtn" name="exbtn">
                </div>
                <div class="appHeader">
                    <!-- 省略 -->
                </div>
                <div class="appLines">
                    <table>
<?php
                //展開用データに入ってる値分ループ
                foreach($datas['cd'] as $key=>$cd){
                    $amount = $datas['amount'][$key];
                    //行を追加
                    print <<<EOB
                        <tr class="appLineDummy">
                            <td><input type="text" value="{$cd}" name="cd[]" style="width:45px; ime-mode: inactive;"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" value="{$amount}" name="amount[]" style="width:45px;"></td>
                            <td><button class="rowins" type="button">+</button></td>
                            <td><button class="rowdel" type="button">-</button></td>
                        </tr>
EOB;
                }
?>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="appBottom">
                    <!-- 省略 -->
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Myaku様 私が知りたいこと全てにお答え頂きました。本当にありがとうございます！
1.おさらいさせて頂きました。
2.INPUT要素以外の要素も、PHP側でリクエスト時点で表示されていた画面内容は取得できる、と解釈しました。
前回の「一度吐き出した後のHTML(クライアント側??)でPHP(サーバ側)の処理を行うことは??出来ません。 」との記載を
当方が勝手に間違った解釈をして　慌てていた自分がいました（できる筈のこともできないと認識してしまうほど）。
3.リクエストされた内容を、配列の変数に格納しておけば、ポストで出せる、ということですね。よく理解できました。
4.Tableの常識的な扱い方についてですね？.NETでコントロールを貼り付けていく癖があって．．．
ソースを当方以外の方が目にする機会も考慮して、前向きに修正を検討します。
冒頭に@を付けてみましたが、これで通知がなされる？？

Myaku様をはじめ、皆様いつもご親切なご支援ありがとうございます。

Comment: @saya24 `@user`を使うときには敬称を付けないか敬称との間に半角スペースを入れると良いです。

Comment: 了解致しました。ひょっとして表示されない

Comment: >4.Tableの常識的な扱い方についてですね？.NETでコントロールを貼り付けていく癖があって．．． ソースを当方以外の方が目にする機会も考慮して、前向きに修正を検討します。 ←Myaku様のTableの見出しの表し方のご提案を、tr中のlabelについてのご見解と勘違いした記載でした、申し訳ございません。（本来はspanとか、そういうことを述べているのかと見当違いをしていました）

Answer (score 0):

質問者さんがコメントでおっしゃっている「つまり自画面のPHPで画面上の内‌​容を処理することを考えてきています。 」というのがそのまんま、formのアクションに自分自身のphpを指定する(参考にされている例だとuranai_result.phpを指定する)ことです。
例では、入力のフォームを部分に記述していますが、これもphpで出力するようにして、

```
<?php  
$html = '';
if (isset($_POST["uranai"])) { 
    if (/* エラー判定 */) {
        // エラーの場合
        $html = <<< EOL
<form action="uranai_result.php" method="post"> 
年齢を教えてください：
<input type="text" name="age" value='
EOL;
        $html += $_POST["age"];
        $html += <<< EOL
'> 
<input type="submit" name="uranai" value="占う！"> 
</form> 
EOL;
    } else {
        // エラーでない場合
        // 結果表示
        (省略)
    }
} else {
    $html = <<< EOL
<form action="uranai_result.php" method="post"> 
年齢を教えてください： 
<input type="text" name="age" value=""> 
<input type="submit" name="uranai" value="占う！"> 
</form> 
EOL;
}
?> 
<html>
<body> 
<?php
if (isset($html)) {
    echo $html;
}
?>
</body> 
</html>
```

こんな感じで記述してみてはどうでしょうか？(ちょっと冗長な書き方ですが、その方が理解しやすいかなと思って書いてます)

Comment: Sugiyama Koichi様　ご支援を賜りまして誠にありがとうございます。早速ご提示の内容をuranai_result.phpとして保存して、開発中のサイトで実行してみましたが、真っ白　テキストボックスも現われない状況でした。何か私の検証が誤っていますかね？

Comment: すみません、コピペで適当なコードを載せてしまっていました。とりあえずちゃんと表示できる(略した部分は埋めてください)ように修正しました。要はsubmitされている場合はPOSTで受け取った値をHTMLの中に埋めるということです。

Comment: Sugiyama Koichi様　貴重なをお時間頂戴しまして誠にありがとうございます。
当方あまりに未熟過ぎて、ご提示頂きましたコーディングを未だ実行できない状況です、せっかくのご好意を．．．すみません。
"エラー判定"のif文の中身、条件がtrueだった場合の処置だけ、自分なりに記述すれば検証は行えるものなでしょうか？
ヒアドキュメントというのも使用経験なくて．．．
（現在コピペして実行すると真っ白）